# h2o code in R is not working - strange error message

Tags: java, pca, h2o

I cannot seem to get the h2o code to load in R. I tried to start up h2o using the following codes:

```
h2o.no_progress()

h2o.init(max_mem_size = "5g")
```

This did not work so I tried the code below and got the following error message.

```
h2o.init()
```

> '''H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
>
> <simpleError in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE): '""' not found>
>
> Error in value[3L] :
>
> You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
>
> Please download the latest Java SE JDK from the following URL:
>
> [https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html'''](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html%27%27%27)

I tried downloading the Java update, but the link does not work. I am not sure how to fix the error. I am trying to do PCA on my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html  Are the double quotes at the end of the link part of the error message?  Or did that get added when you formatted your question here?  If you remove the quotes at the end, the link works.

Please download Java 11 because Java 14 (the latest) was just released and we don't officially support it yet.  H2O system requirements (Java 8-13) are listed [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html#requirements).